# Can't find correct encoding to save file with special characters

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, save

I have a problem with saving file with some special characters like foreign letters and symbols f.e. d’Aguesseau or ».

I am reading the text from txt file (using utf-8 and everything looks fine) and then I am doing some processing and I would like to save the dataframe that is containing some of those special characters. I was trying df.to_csv() with different encodings but they either: save the file putting in place of special characters some strange things like dâ€™Aguesseau or are giving an error saying that some of the characters can't be decoded.

Comment: If you see "â€™" in the saved file it most probably means that the CSV was successfully saved with UTF-8, but Excel (or whatever you used to view the file) didn't realise it should use UTF-8 to decode the file. You can help MS tools by saving with "utf-8-sig", which adds a byte-order mark (BOM) at the beginning.

Comment: Ahhh, so saving was correct all this time. I'm new to this topic and I thought I am gonna go crazy while figuring this. Thousand thanks, man!